# How do you call a Spock test from another Groovy class and return the result?

Tags: groovy, spock

How do you call a Spock test from another Groovy class and return the result?

Comment: What do you mean return the result? Please explain what exactly you already tried and what exactly you want to achieve. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to SO. Where is your code? What are you trying to achieve? Like this, the question is only going to attract close voters.